# HTML comment missing symmetry

Tags: html, comments, symmetry

In HTML we usually do comments alike:

```
<!-- Comment here -->
```

Why is the comment not symmetrical as in:

```
<!-- Comment here --!>
```

I'm looking for the historical answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please look into [HTML 2.0 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866#section-3.2.5)
here's and interesting part:

> To include comments in an HTML document, use a comment declaration. A
> comment declaration consists of `<!' followed by zero or more comments followed by` >'. Each comment starts with `--' and includes all text up to and including the next occurrence of` --'. In a
> comment declaration, white space is allowed after each comment, but
> not before the first comment.  The entire comment declaration is
> ignored.

> NOTE - Some historical HTML implementations incorrectly consider
> any `>' character to be the termination of a comment.

> For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<HEAD>
<TITLE>HTML Comment Example</TITLE>
<!-- Id: html-sgml.sgm,v 1.5 1995/05/26 21:29:50 connolly Exp  -->
<!-- another -- -- comment -->
<!>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<p> <!- not a comment, just regular old data characters ->
```

Comment: I don't believe this answer adresses the symmetry that the question is about. Even though it is an interesting answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, it's because it's derived from SGML where that used to be the standard

From [sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/html-xhtml-syntax):

> The HTML comment looks like this: . It’s derived from SGML, which starts with an `<!` and ends with an `>`

[This page](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/SGMLComments.html#doubledash) has quite some information about the history of HTML and SGML

Comment: Interesting, but the question remains as to why SGML decided for a asymmetric comment indicator scheme.